# Passing table name as a parameter in pyodbc

Tags: python, database, sql-server-2005, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to pass a table name in `pyodbc` as a parameter to access data from ms sql 2005. I've tried to substitute it with `?` but it never works. I would be glad to receive any advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using pyodbc, I assume you are not calling a SPROC. 
I recommend building your SQL string in python and then passing it to SQL to execute.

```
import pyodbc
dbconn = pyodbc.connect(ConnectionString)
c = dbconn.cursor()

j = 'table1' #where table1 is entered, retreived, etc
query = "Select * from %s" % j
c.execute(query)
result = c.fetchall()
print 'Done'
```

Comment: Just be careful that the table name is not coming from user input or browser feedback - that's the setup for SQL injection.

Comment: @Mark, you make an excellent point.  But table names at least are somewhat easier to sanitize than certain other types of input into SQL.

Comment: This is a quite old answer. Does anyone know if pyodbc has added some safer way to do this by now? Something similiar to [`psycopg2.sql.SQL`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL) template objects, maybe? (psycopg2 is a PostgreSQL database adapter for Python)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have variable as a table name SQL Server. You need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for that to work.

Look here for how to deal with dynamic table names. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames

Comment: I found the sweet way to do it! I will share soon!