# Python - Passing datetime parameters into a SQL Command

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to do something like this in Python,

```
SQLCommand = ("Delete From %s where [Date] >= %s and [Date] <= %s", (calendar_table_name, required_starting_date, required_ending_date))

cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
```

`calendar_table_name` is a `string` variable

`required_starting_date` is a `datetime` variable

`required_ending_date` is a `datetime` variable

Trying this gives me an error:

> The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

Tried this and it gives me the same error:

```
SQLCommand = ("Delete From " +  calendar_table_name + " where [Date] >= %s and [Date] <= %s", ( required_starting_date, required_ending_date))

cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
```

Edit:

```
type(required_ending_date)

Out[103]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp


type(required_starting_date)

Out[103]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

This works in SSMS for me,

```
  delete from [table_test] where [Date] >= '2007-01-01' and [Date] <= '2021-01-01';
```

**Update :- This is the code, that I am trying with**

```
Delete_SQLCommand =  f"Delete FROM [{calendar_table_name}] WHERE [Date]>=? And [Date]<=?"
params = (required_starting_date, required_ending_date)
```

required_starting_date & required_ending_date are of "TimeStamp" formats

```
calendar_tbl_connection = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=required_server, database=database_name,
                     trusted_connection='yes')   
calendar_tbl_cursor = calendar_tbl_connection.cursor()
calendar_tbl_cursor.execute(Delete_SQLCommand,params)
calendar_tbl_connection.commit
calendar_tbl_connection.close()
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize table names. `From %s where` is not valid in this case. You need to use string formatting to make dynamic table names, then pass the parameters for the rest of the query

Comment: You haven't shown us how this sql command is _used_.  Show us the call to `execute()`.

Comment: Right, so the edit suggests that you're passing a `datetime` object and not a string, and either the column is configured to take TEXT values (or similar) or your connection library won't do the conversion to ISO format

Comment: @tgikal That's how you get SQL injection attacks.  Don't do it that way.

Comment: @tgikal they definitely did not mean that

Comment: @tgikal Tried what you mentioned and it gives me this error on cursor.execute command - ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '00'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Make `SQLCommand` be just the string portion, i.e. `SQLCommand = "Delete From ..."` .  Then call execute with the arguments: `cursor.execute(SQLCommand, (arg1, arg2))`

Comment: @roganjosh I guess that would really depend on what filter is done on `required_starting_date` and `required_ending_date` before the query.

Comment: @Siddharth please do _not_ do what they suggested. Your attempt, albeit currently broken, is much better practice. Please print the `type` of the parameters you are passing

Comment: @tgikal assume _every filter fails_ and do it the correct way, all the time. Not only is it more secure, but it has better syntax anyway and will be faster

Comment: I'm not sure where these suggestions are going. The error states that the parameter should be a string and it's not, so the first port of call should be checking the type of the parameters that are being inserted into the query

Comment: Look for libraries that support (or hope your library supports) safe dynamic construction of SQL queries instead of using string formatting. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql for an example.

Comment: You write that "required_starting_date is a datetime variable", but the exception message indicates that it's in fact a pandas Timestamp object. Also you should tell us which database adaptor library you are using. I've added the `pyodbc` tag, since you mentioned that in a comment, but you should edit the question to add relevant information about the libraries you are using (pandas, pyodbc). That way we can reproduce your problem and suggest solutions that might be specific to those libraries. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc has no problem dealing with pandas' `Timestamp` values as inputs to a proper *parameterized query:*

```python
# test data
calendar_table_name = "#calendar_table"
crsr.execute(f"CREATE TABLE [{calendar_table_name}] ([Date] date)")
crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO [{calendar_table_name}] VALUES ('2019-08-22'),('2019-08-24')")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(datetime(2019, 8, 23, 0, 0), datetime(2019, 8, 25, 0, 0))],
    columns=['required_starting_date', 'required_ending_date'])
required_starting_date = df.iloc[0][0]
required_ending_date = df.iloc[0][1]
print(type(required_starting_date))  # <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# test
sql = f"DELETE FROM [{calendar_table_name}] WHERE [Date]>=? AND [Date]<=?"
params = (required_starting_date, required_ending_date)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
cnxn.commit()

#verify
rows = crsr.execute(f"SELECT * FROM [{calendar_table_name}]").fetchall()
print(rows)  # [(datetime.date(2019, 8, 22), )]
```

Comment: The Select statement that you have in test works. But If I change my query to delete then it fails. Sorry couldn't get back to this sooner.

Comment: Fails how? Do you get an exception?

Comment: No, it just doesn't delete it. The Query runs but the data doesn't gets deleted.

Comment: Are you remembering to do a `commit()`?

Comment: If you are using SSMS to check the results of the delete then double-check that you are connecting to the same SQL Server instance that your Python app is working on.

Comment: 100% - I am checking the same instance as that is the only instance that I have.

Comment: As my updated sample code shows, this approach works just as well for DELETE as it does for SELECT. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] *including sample data*.

Comment: Not sure why, Finally it worked. It started working when I add a line called as "Connection.AutoCommit = True" before the line where I am already commiting. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which library you are using for SQL access, but here is a safe example using `psycopg`.

```
from psycopg2 import sql

cmd = sql.SQL("delete from {} where date >= %s and date <= %s")
table_name = sql.Identifier(calendar_table_name)
cur.execute(
    cmd.format(table_name),
    [required_starting_date, required_ending_date]
)
```

Note that this is *not* `str.format` being called, but `SQL.format`. The library ensures that `calendar_table_name` is a proper column name, and `SQL.format` ensures that it is correctly incorporated into your command template before in order to produce a valid parameterized query.

---

Failing proper library support, you would need to do *some* sort of dynamic query generation. It should be a *restricted* sort, though, the more restricted the better. The safest way would be to start with a lookup table of hard-coded queries:

```
queries = {
  'name1': 'delete from name1 where ... ',
  'name2': 'delete from name2 where ...',
}
```

This way, you *can't* construct a query for an arbitrary table name, only select a pre-constructed query.

The second would be to wrap the constructor in a function that checks for a valid table name first. For example,

```
def generate_query(table_name):
    if table_name not in ['name1', 'name2', ...]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid table name")

    return "delete from {} where ...".format(table_name)
```

Comment: I am using pyodbc

Comment: @Siddarth: This might still work, python has a standardized database connector api. If pyodbc follows it, `cursor.execute` should work much the same as with pyscopg2 (postgres).

Comment: @HåkenLid The classes provided by `psycopg2.sql` are not part of the DBAPI.

Comment: Ok. So even if the cursor.execute method works fine, the equivalent of  `sql.Identifier` and `sql.SQL` in your answer might be missing from pyodbc? It would be possible to just use string formatting, I suppose. But then you would have to be careful that the table name variable is safe. I found a relevant question, but the highest answer there looks like it could expose a sql injection vulnerability: [Passing table name as a parameter in pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669009/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-pyodbc).

Comment: @HåkenLid you can get a reference list of the schema of your database and check any variable input against that list ("does this 'table' actually exist?") before execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 (at least) different problems with this code:

1. You are using pandas Timestamp types instead of the expected python datetime types. [Roganosh answer explains that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630726/1977847)
2. You are mixing sql identifiers (table name) with sql values (date). You can only pass values as parameters to `cursor.execute`. [see chepner's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)
3. You are calling `cursor.execute` with incorrect arguments.

`cursor.execute` expects two arguments. Since your `SQLCommand` variable is a tuple, you can use `*` to unpack the query string and the variables into two arguments when calling `cursor.execute`.

```
SQLCommand = (
    "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date >= %s", 
    (datetime.date(2019, 08, 23),) 
)

cursor.execute(*SQLCommand)
```

Note that you can't pass sql identfiers such as table names as parameters to the `cursor.execute` method. [The Python Database API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) does not specify how to construct queries with dynamic identifiers (for example column or table names).

Comment: This only works for query parameters, not the table name. The DBAPI itself does not support full dynamic generation of SQL commands.

Comment: @chepner: You are right. There are two problems with the code in the question. My answer addresses why they get the error "The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query." in this case. I've edited the answer to make it clearer that parameters (the second argument to `cursor.execute` must be values, not identifiers such as table names.